# I am stuck in an xcode 8 situation

Tags: swift, image, xcode8

I am currently making a calculator, and I am using Swift, with XCode 8. I have already defined a variable, but when I want to connect it to my button and text field, it says use of unresolved identifier. Can anyone help me?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please only tag languages that your question actually involves.

Comment: Please paste code instead of images.

Comment: Your variable is clearly in another scope than the place you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sum` variable is defined inside the `Solve` function scope, so it can only be used inside that scope. You have to make your variable global (i.e. inside the `UIViewController` scope) for it to be visible inside all the functions.

- Define `var sum` outside the function, under `Oranges`.

  ```
  class ViewController : UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var Apples :UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var Oranges :UITextField!
      var sum : String!

      @IBAction func Solve(_ sender: AnyObject)
      {
          var apples = Int(Apples.text!)
          var oranges = Int(Oranges.text!)
          sum = String(oranges! + apples!)
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Dude how? where should I define the variable?

Comment: But when I do this and keep all my other code the same, it says that the oranges and the apples in the var sum are unresolved identifiers. I seriously don't understand

Comment: cannot use instance member 'apples' within property initializer. This is where i am defining my variables, yet it makes this error, and I am using the exact same variable names for the 2 IBOutlets and the Int(oranges.text)

Comment: sokay man I figured it out. I just defined the output and the three variable all in the same place and it works now. Thanks for making me aware of scoping.